# Set Expiry for Offline setup Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, registry, web-deployment

Primarily am new to Developing.

I have Built a Setup File for my c# web Application using VS 2017. Am Going to Deploy my Setup in client Computer with Expiry Date which will be stored in registry. My setup can work in offline. But i want to collect/gather Client data weekly once. So What all i want is , let my client to use my setup without internet for one week. after that my setup have to become expired. Then he/she must connect with internet to extend an expiry date for Next one week. Kindly Help Me to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create new form for `read/write/check registry for check registration date and check with current date` and add that for main form (first opening form, for this you can change form name in `program.cs`) , also you can add method in current main form and run that method in `load events`, after check you can chose between start program or show dialog for connect and extend or etc..

small code :

```
public partial class Reg_Form : Form
    {

        private string Reg_path = "Software\\MySampleProgram";
        private string Reg_key = "Expire";
        public Reg_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            check_expire_date();
        }

        private void check_expire_date()
        {
            bool exists_key = check_reg();
            if (!exists_key)
            {
                //first use, so we need to write expire date
                bool is_write = write_reg();
                if (!is_write)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Run program as administrator and try again.");
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            var dt = read_reg_val();
            if (dt != null)
            {
                DateTime current_date = DateTime.UtcNow;
                DateTime reg_date = DateTime.UtcNow;

                DateTime.TryParse(dt, out reg_date);

                var res = (current_date - reg_date).TotalDays;
                if (res < 7)
                {
                    Main_Form frm = new Main_Form();
                    this.Hide();
                    frm.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please connect to internet for extend time !");
                    //do any other work.....
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error, try again !");
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        private bool write_reg()
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
                key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(Reg_path);
                key.SetValue(Reg_key, DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString());
                key.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        private bool check_reg()
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Reg_path);
                if (key != null)
                {
                    Object o = key.GetValue(Reg_key);
                    if (o != null)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
        private string read_reg_val()
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Reg_path);
                if (key != null)
                {
                    Object o = key.GetValue(Reg_key);
                    if (o != null)
                    {
                        string res = o as String;
                        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                        bool ok_date = DateTime.TryParse(res, out dt);
                        if (ok_date)
                        {
                            return res;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //changed value by user or hacked !
                            DateTime today = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            DateTime sevenDaysEarlier = today.AddDays(-8);
                            return sevenDaysEarlier.ToShortDateString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

---

Note : this is note perfect, user can change the time & date on PC Or if can find registry can change and bypass expiry date, however it's good sample for you.

if problem solved, so please don't forget to mark answer as accepted/solved.